# One likes to do it oneself. (Who is one?)

Tags: pronouns

One likes to do it oneself.

Who is "one"?

1. I
2. one of people in general

Comment: In the example: the speaker, but 'one' does not mean 'me'. So one would not say "One likes to do it oneself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The royalty/aristocracy of Britain are often characterised as using "one" to mean "I".  This has become a rather hackneyed joke amongst comedians.

In every other case "one" is the impersonal pronoun. It is rarely used these days except in formal writing. It would sound pretentious in everyday conversation in my opinion.

---

Note: I use it occasionally on this website. I never use it in conversation - I would be ridiculed.

Comment: In modern times people tend to use 'you' instead of 'one' to mean "people in general" but it still suffers from the same mis-use, especially when objectivizing an unpleasant experience. It sounds jarring to me when someone says "you did this, you thought that" and I am thinking "No, I didn't, please cop to it. It was *you*." They aren't talking generally.

Comment: I have conversations every day at work in which 'one' is not out of place.

Comment: Its use is common in some contexts, as in: **One doesn't ask questions**, meaning that it's not wise to do so.

Comment: @WeatherVane - some people seem incapable of phasing remarks about people in general without using 'you'. I agree that it is annoying.

Comment: I don't think that using 'one' sounds pretentious. Not at all.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, as an American, either of these usages sounds at least a bit pretentious to me. OP: if you're writing for an international audience, I'd recommend to avoid using *one* as a pronoun altogether.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Not a problem. But OP might not be aware of the difference between British and American usage. The usage isn't unknown in America, as your example shows.  But it is somewhat pretentious --- the kind of thing you say when you're a politician unveiling a statue.

Comment: The wonderful New York Times: "... the great white whale of American politics — or one of them, at least — has finally been found. On Sunday, The Times published an investigation of President Trump’s tax records that he has for years fought to conceal, and the findings were striking: Through claims of staggering business losses, a dubious refund scheme and questionable write-offs (e.g., expensing $70,000 for hairstyling, as one does), Mr. Trump was able to reduce his federal income tax bill in 10 of the 15 years before his election to $0. In 2016 and 2017, he paid just $750 a year."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, the NYT is also known for its pretentious style. It may be relevant that I'm a west-coast American, and we tend to be substantially more informal than New Yorkers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I would consider something pretentious if said in a way that excessively highlights the speaker's importance or intelligence, even if they are very important or intelligent. For example is George Will very intelligent? Yes, he is. Is he a bit pretentious about it? Yes, he is also a bit pretentious about it.

Comment: Well, I agree, but in British registers above the most informal, one might very well talk like that.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - yes, it was Gov. Andrew M. Cuomo.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I was commenting about British conversation. I think my remarks would hold in large parts of the British English zone of the world, except maybe Australia. Regarding America, Gov. Andrew M. Cuomo said in October 2020 "We all know that these are challenging times, but we also know that in the book of life, it is not what one does when the sun is shining that tests our mettle, It’s what one does in the fury of the storm." He was unveiling a statue of Mother Cabrini, the nun who died in 1917 after decades of caring for the sick and poor.

Answer (score 5):

[Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/one) considers this usage to be that of a grammatical pronoun, and as such it conforms to the third definition in that section: “*[third person singular]* Used to refer to the speaker, or any person, as representing people in general”. This is in essence your second choice, “one of the people in general”.